# Error Message: NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"._5qtp"}

Tags: css, python-3.x, facebook, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I was trying the following code for an automated status update on Facebook with selenium.

I copied it from some website to learn about selenium.
Here the web driver could not find the class or the id of the box in which we write status.

I even searched for it with the inspect panel, but I didn't get any proper id or class and the above error prompted. Please help me!

How can I find the XPath or id the status update box?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

import time
### login details ########################
username = "xxxxxxx@xxxxx.xxx"
pwd = "xxxxxxxxx"
##########################################

### what is on my mind ###################
msg = "hey there!"
##########################################

# initializing driver and loading web
chrome_path = r"chromedriver.exe"
options = Options()
options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path, chrome_options=options)
driver.get("http://www.facebook.com/")
# end initializing

# start login
user_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="email"]""")
pwd_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="pass"]""")
user_input.send_keys(username)
pwd_input.send_keys(pwd)
pwd_input.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
# end login

# writing msg
time.sleep(3)
first_what_is_on_my_mind_element = driver.find_element_by_class_name("_5qtp")
first_what_is_on_my_mind_element.click()
time.sleep(3)
second_what_is_on_my_mind_element = driver.switch_to.active_element
second_what_is_on_my_mind_element.send_keys(msg)
# end writing

# posting
buttons = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('button')
for button in buttons:
    if 'Post' in button.text:
        button.click()
# end posting
```

Comment: Facebook doesn't allow you to scrape them. Use the API. And if it is not possible in the API then you can't do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, I suggest, you proceed the work step by step in a shell and test your code in progress.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

#This part is for opening the webdriver with proxy (since FB is prohibited here!)
proxy="127.0.0.1:0000"
chrome_options=webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=socks5://' + proxy)
driver=webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

# Let's open the FB and insert Username and Password:
driver.get("https://www.facebook.com")

# Give the username by copying the full XPath and send keys:
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/form/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/input").send_keys("Username") 

#Same for the Password:
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/form/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/input").send_keys("Password")

#Click the login button, you also can send Return key to password field:
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/form/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]/label/input").click()

#Hitting the status bar:
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div").click() 

#giving the status message:
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[4]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/form/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div").send_keys("This is a test status from an automation :)")

#Hit the Post button:
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[4]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/form/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div").click()

#Enjoy the code :)
```

I have tested the above code and it works perfectly. You can find the Full-Xpath as shown in below:
[image: How to copy full XPath]

---

Edited:
First of all, forget about XPath for the Login page. Because it is relative to the browser condition. Instead, use the CSS Selector as below code:
(It has also webdriver option for disabling notification which might solve the error of not finding status element)

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

username=str(input("Please enter your FB username:\n"))
password=str(input("Please enter your FB password:\n"))
proxy=str(input("Please enter your proxy:\n"))


#This part is for opening the webdriver with proxy (since FB is prohibited here!)
chrome_options=webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=socks5://' + proxy)

# Making Notifications off automatically
prefs = {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications" : 2}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)
driver=webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

# Let's open the FB and insert Username and Password:
driver.get("https://www.facebook.com")

# Give the username by copying the css_selector and send keys:
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input#email.inputtext.login_form_input_box").send_keys(username)
#Same for the Password:
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input#pass.inputtext.login_form_input_box").send_keys(username)

#Click the login button, you also can send Return key to password field:
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("label#loginbutton.login_form_login_button.uiButton.uiButtonConfirm").click()
#Hitting the status bar:
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div").click() 

#giving the status message:
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[4]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/form/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div").send_keys("This is a test status from an automation :)")

#Hit the Post button:
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[4]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/form/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div").click()
```

BTW, this is the way to select an element by mouse and in below picture you can see the CSS Selector name for Username field:
(If you right-click on any element, while the inspector is on, you can find Copy>full XPath to copy the XPath)

[image: Using Inspector tool for showing css selector item]

Comment: `NoSuchElementException                    Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-47785b552a4e> in <module>
     23 
     24 #Hitting the status bar:
---> 25 driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div").click()`

Comment: Thanks a lot, brother I tried this code. But the above error occurred! Please review it!

Comment: Can you please show me, how to get the XPath for the status bar?

Comment: Does it ask you for Notifications approval? If so, I have to add some options to the driver to turn off FB notifications automatically.

Comment: Dear brother,
I have added another kind of code to turn off the notification which prevented selecting status field.

Comment: Also I have changed the login procedure to use css selector, which is more reliable than XPath.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219463/discussion-between-the-shend-and-samar-pratap-singh).